# Continuous integration + "deployment" of npm modules?

Tags: npm, travis-ci

Scenario:

- I'm **continuously integrating** + **deploying** a Node web app on every commit to master, e.g. via Travis to Heroku.

  (Two options: [Travis's deploy hook](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/), or [Heroku's GitHub Sync](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration). Importantly, both ways only deploy **if CI succeeds / tests pass**.)
- I have some pieces of this app that I want to maintain as **separate, reusable modules**, e.g. in their own git repos.
- Let's assume everything is **public** for simplicity.

—

I want to similarly continuously integrate + "deploy" (i.e. make available to the app) these modules, on every commit to *their* master (or w/e branch):

- Every time I update my web app, I want to use the **latest stable** (i.e. **tested**) version of these modules.
- Importantly, if I accidentally commit a bug to a module, and **CI fails**, an update to the web app should *not* pick up this change.
- I don't want to **manually** bump a version, or publish a tag, or etc. on every commit.

—

I've investigated a number of options, but can't find any simple way to achieve all three of these goals!

- **[npm git dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies):** I can point my web app's `package.json` directly at each module's GitHub repo (e.g. `"foo": "git://github.com/alice/foo.git#1.x"`) to get continuous "deployment" (availability) of that module's repo. But if I accidentally commit a bug, apps are broken on their next deploy, even if the module's CI fails.
- **[Travis npm publish](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/):** Travis can automatically publish the module to npm after a successful CI, but the npm registry requires a unique version each time, and there's no way to automatically bump the version AFAICT.
- **[Travis GitHub release](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/):** I was hoping Travis could automatically update a tag, but it can only do this *on* tags (it's meant more for publishing build assets), so still manual.

—

Is there any way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that comes to mind, though it would need to be manually implemented, would be to update a branch (named e.g. `stable` or `tested` or w/e) on Travis `after_success` (sort of like a manual deploy hook).

Then, you could freely commit to master, but this other branch would only contain commits that passed CI. This'd allow you to point npm at this branch, e.g. `foo.git#stable`. And if you updated via a non-force `git push`, you're guaranteed that this branch would only contain ffwd commits.

You'd need to make GitHub user creds available to the script, e.g. via secure env vars, but they can be the same ones that Travis itself uses. I'm not sure if there'll be any other gotchas though. E.g. I assume git is available to Travis scripts.

Comment: It'd be slick if Travis offered this as a built-in deploy option!